# floated div, height 100, container fluid height

Tags: css, html, height, css-float

I have this [design](http://m.kolbecdn.com/) which I cannot seem to get right, I would like .sidebar (float:left) to fill the entire height of .page-container which has a fluid height due to the content. How do I go about this?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/791231/css-sidebar-height-100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop the `margin-bottom` and `margin-left` on `.page-top` and remove the `margin-left` from `.sidebar`. Once you do this, you have a lot of empty space at the top of `.page-container` but I don't understand your layout enough to comment on what to do about that; no offense, but you have a lot of empty `<div>` elements which I don't understand, and which are in turn causing you to abuse `margins` in my opinion, only making your layout harder to understand and work with.

Then you'll be ready to use the [Faux columns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/) trick described in the possible duplicate. The heart of the idea is `.sidebar` doesn't stretch all the way, but `.page-container` has a background which creates the impression it does.