# My CSS sidebar isnt working, height issue

Tags: css

Could someone please help me with my CSS side bar, it would fill in height. Please help

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7Qp4E)

```
.sidebar1 {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    background: #93A5C4;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
}
```

Comment: css trick is: you will need to set all the .sidebar1 parents and body, html to 100%

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS Sidebar Height 100%](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/791231/css-sidebar-height-100)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the height of the html / body like

`body, html {
    height: 100%;
}`

http://jsfiddle.net/7Qp4E/1/

Answer (score 0):

css trick is: you will need to set all the .sidebar1 parents and body, html to 100%

Comment: This looks like more of a comment than an answer. Please provide some explanation and a code example. (FYI, this answer and the other one I just commented on were both marked for the Low Quality Posts review queue. Answers should be comprehensive and self-contained, not just quick one-line pointers in the right direction or links to other sites.)