# Display issue: right content cont bleeds over onto left column on mobile

Tags: html, ios, css, mobile

My problem is that on mobile, the right cont (white background) goes underneath the left cont (purple). I have tried using `clear:both` and it still didn't fix it.

I keep thinking this CSS is wrong:

```
.cont {
    width: 1000px;
    overflow: hidden
}
.cont_left {
    width: 283px;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    vertical-align: central;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    background-image: url(.//images/sidebar.png);
    padding-bottom: 220px;
}
.cont_right {
    width: 600px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    position:relative;
    font: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    background: #ffffff;
    padding-right: 25px;
}
```

Live site: [Website](http://www.securadesktop.com/)

Image of problem: [iOS Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzNyx.png)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for the [Faux Columns](http://alistapart.com/article/fauxcolumns) technique, which has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791231/css-sidebar-height-100). Also, Geoff Graham has written a pretty well covered [article](https://css-tricks.com/left-and-right/) about spliting your layout in half (but of course, you don't need to go 50 50 as described).

In your case, I'd go with percentages (70% for the content, 30% for the side bar), using one of the techniques mentioned above. And be careful, as  `vertical-align: central;` is not a valid property. [Here](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/) you can find some info about how to center stuff vertically.

Comment: Thanks for the links/tips.

Comment: Anytime. Just remember to upvote if the answer has helped you in anyway.

Answer (score 0):

so its just the css for the left side is wrong. you have got the bg image on repeat. the top part of the image repeated is white so it looks like the right side is bleeding over....

```
.cont_left {
  background-color: #23265d !important;
  background-image: url(".//images/sidebar.png");
  background-position: left top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  float: left;
  height: auto;
  padding: 25px 25px 220px;
  width: 283px;
}
```

this will fix it

Comment: This unfortunately hasn't fixed it. I have updated the live website with this CSS and still have problems with mobile.

Comment: perhaps clear your phone browser cache. the purple goes all the way to the bottom.

Comment: May I ask what phone/browser? I am looking from an iPhone 5s - Chrome browser.

Comment: Safari n chrome in Samsung s5